# Accessing an href value using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath

Tags: perl, xpath

I am using the [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent),
[`HTML::Selector::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aSelector%3a%3aXPath) and
[`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath) modules to get the value of the `href` attribute of the first YouTube video in a set of search results.

My code so far is:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use HTML::Selector::XPath;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

#my $response =..
my $html = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=run+flo+rida";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new;

my $xpath = HTML::Selector::XPath::selector_to_xpath("(//*[@id = 'search-results']/li)[1]/div[2]/h3/a/@href/");
my @nodes = $tree->findnodes($xpath);
print" $nodes[0]";
```

I'm not sure if my printing is incorrect of if some other syntax is wrong. As of now it prints

```
HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath=HASH(0x1a78250)
```

when I am looking for it to print

```
/watch?v=JP68g3SYObU
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of problems here.

- You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program. It will catch many errors that you would easily overlook, and is only polite when you are asking for help with your code. In this case it would have warned you that your XPath string contained array variable names `@id` and `@href` which you may not have intended to be interpolated into the string.
- You are using `HTML::Selector::XPath`, which translates a CSS selector to an XPath expression. But you are supplying it an XPath expression, so it will not work and the module is not needed.
- There is no need to use `LWP` at all, as `HTML::TreeBuilder` has a `new_from_url` constructor which will fetch the HTML page for you.

This program seems to do what you need. I have also added the `URI` module to derive an absolute URL from the relative one in the `href` attribute value.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use URI;

my $url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=run+flo+rida";

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_url($url);

my $anchor = $tree->findnodes('//ol[@id="search-results"]//h3[@class="yt-lockup2-title"]/a/@href');
my $href = URI->new_abs($anchor->[0]->getValue, $url);
print $href;
```

**output**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP68g3SYObU
```

Comment: wow thank you so much i will take your advice and always use strict and warning. This is perfect!